# Webpack bundled packages can't find peer dependencies in vite_rails project

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, webpack, vite

I have a rails project that I'm migrating from webpacker to vite.js and a number of my private packages, bundled with webpack all are built with react and so the rails project was setup with webpack and installed react/-dom itself for use in these installed packages.

In the webpacker config I had to setup aliases for most of these so they could find React and React Dom.

```
const { resolve } = require('path');

module.exports = {
  React: resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/react'),
  ReactDOM: resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/react-dom'),
  "react": resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/react'),
  "react-dom": resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/react-dom'),
  AsyncStorage: resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'),
  Pusher: resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/pusher-js')
}
```

But I can't find in the vite.js or rollup.js documentation where or even if I have to do something similar. [This section](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html) of vite's docs makes me think that it's supposed to just be handling it magically but appears to not be.

Here's an example of the error I'm getting:

```
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "ReactDOM"

    node_modules/skarsnik/bundled/plugin.js:1:107:
      1 │ ...of exports&&"object"==typeof module?module.exports=e(require("React"),require("ReactDOM"),require("GobblaPackage")):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["Re...
        ╵                                                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "ReactDOM" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this
  error. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at
  run-time instead of bundle-time.
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

#### EDIT

also looking at one of the webpack bundled packages I have `externals` config which may explain the "Could not resolve 'ReactDOM'":

```
 externals: {
    'react':     "React",
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    '@realgeeks/gobbla/bundled/plugin': "GobblaPackage",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "AsyncStorage"
  }
```